# How to print the output to a file in jupyter?

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I want to print the output to a PDF file in jupyter notebook

I am using this command:

jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb

but when I run it the program says

jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Where are you running the command? From what you are sharing it seems you are trying to run that inside Python or in a Jupyter notebook in a Python kernel. That is a command line command, as stated, "The command-line syntax to run the nbconvert syntax" in the [documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-as-a-command-line-tool). You run it in the terminal or put an exclamation point in front of it and try it in Jupyter that has a Python kernel. There's a `--to pdf` option.